# Flatten and back keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I am trying to get values in the simple vector using autoencoder

here is my code

```
input_img = Input(shape=(28, 28, 1))

x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
encoded = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
```

Here I need a flatten layer

```
encoder = Model(input_img, encoded)
```

And then make it convolutional back

```
encoderOutputShape = encoded._keras_shape[1:]

# unflatten here
decoder_input= Input(encoderOutputShape)
decoder = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(decoder_input)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(decoder)
x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
decoded = Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)

decoder = Model(decoder_input, decoded)

auto_input = Input(shape=(28,28,1))

encoded = encoder(auto_input)
decoded = decoder(encoded)

auto_encoder = Model(auto_input, decoded)
```

How to do it in the right way?

In other words, I want to get the output of the encoder (or use random data), change it and put into the decoder and get the decoded result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a question here why do you flat the tensor if you don't use any `Dense` layers?

but you can make like this:

```
encoder_output = Flatten()(encoded)
decoder_input = Reshape((7, 7, 32))(encoder_output)

decoder = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(decoder_input)
```

that is because you need to reshape your tensor before.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Yes, I need `Dense` layer in between, but only one. How can I use your code to get encoder and decoder which I can use separately?

Comment: `decoder_input= Input(Reshape((7,7,32))(encoderOutputShape)` this does not work

Comment: Input(Reshape((7,7,32))(encoderOutputShape)) sorry missed to close the last parenthesys

Comment: I get: TypeError: Tensor objects are only iterable when eager execution is enabled. To iterate over this tensor use tf.map_fn.